# Authenticating via Okta that uses 2FA

Tags: authentication, okta, multi-factor-authentication

I built a simple asp.net core application and need to authenticate an account that uses MFA in addition to username & password.

The service I'm trying to log into exposes an authentication endpoint described here:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/authn/#request-example-for-primary-authentication-with-public-application

When I provide the username and password  it returns the expected JSON:

```
{
    "stateToken": "00zQZJ1ZY3Em2401r4T69Dhx35TdF1VTFP5KRTa8ib",
    "expiresAt": "2020-05-30T21:11:14.000Z",
    "status": "MFA_REQUIRED",
    "_embedded": {
        "user": {
            "id": "00u10vk1torIgBBxxxxx",
            "profile": {
                "login": "john.doe@email.com",
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "locale": "en",
                "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
            }
        },
        "factors": [{
                "id": "ost1g59468dXOddAE0h8",
                "factorType": "token:software:totp",
                "provider": "OKTA",
                "vendorName": "OKTA",
                "profile": {
                    "credentialId": "john.doe@email.com"
                },
                "_links": {
                    "verify": {
                        "href": "https://company.okta.com/api/v1/authn/factors/ost1g59468dXOddxxxxx/verify",
                        "hints": {
                            "allow": ["POST"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
```

Does anyone know who I can also add 2FA into the request to get it to work?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: No, I used a different work around entirely.